# get values of row-inputs in table React

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have a form that includes a dynamic table (nx2) that has inputs in every row. When I submit the form, I need to save all those inputs' values in an array. It should look something like:
[['M',10],['S',10],.......].
I'm not finding a way to achieve this, I've seen I have to differentiate each input but I don't know how to access the value later.

This is my code for the table:

```
<table class="table-size-qty">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th scope="col">Size</th>
          <th scope="col">Qty</th>
       </tr>
       {rows.map((r) => (
          <tr>
             <td><input className="no-style" name={'size'+r} type="text"></input></td>
             <td><input className="no-style" name={'qty'+r} type="number"></input></td>
          </tr>
        ))}
    </thead>
</table>
<button type='button' class="buttonAddRow" onClick={addRow}>Add row</button>
```

On every click it adds a row trough the addRow() method:

```
 const addRow = () => {
      setRows([...rows, rows.length]);
 }
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what do the 'M' and 'S' in [['M',10],['S',10],.......] stand for?

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing, it was just an example. The columns are for size and quantity, so the array should have size-qty pairs. 'M' would be a size and 10 the quantity.

Comment: not sure if i understand your question correctly, let's try my answer below

Comment: oh sorry, just seen this comment. yeah, I think I couldn't express myself correctly. was I better this time? haha

Comment: i'll explain it again: I'm working with a marketplace where sellers can upload their clothes. in the clothes' form, there's a table that refers to the size and qty of the product. as I can't know hoy many sizes they have of each product, I decided to implement a dynamic table where they can add as many rows as they want. In this table, they type all the sizes and their corresponding qty in the inputs I was talking about. When they click on "submit product", I need to save all those size-qty values in an array and I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when you add a new row, you're supposed to know the new size-qty values:

```
// newSize, newQty are available
 const addRow = () => {
      setRows([...rows, [newSize, newQty]]);
 }
```

so the `rows` state now will have the structure as you expected, you can render it like:

```
{rows.map(([size, qty]) => (
  <tr>
      <td><input className="no-style" name={`size${size}`} value={size} type="text"></input></td>
      <td><input className="no-style" name={`qty${qty}`} value={qty} type="number"></input></td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Updated, try the demo below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ebcpff

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the size-qty values are written in the input after adding the row. And my problem is not much about the rendering part, but rather that I don't know how to save all the input values in an array once I submit the button :)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have so many inputs, try to have only 2 inputs for size and qty then click add button to add that into the `rows`

Comment: @pop try the demo attached

Comment: aw thank you very much for your time!! different perspective, but I like it even more haha. I'll definitely use that. thanks again, really!!!!